# PostgreSQL docker container fails to mount volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to run this command `docker-compose up` on this `docker-compose.yml` file

My machine is running Windows 10 Home Edition Version 2004, which supports running the docker containers on a WSL 2 Backend.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes: 
        - ./docker-data/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
  adminer:
    depends_on:
        - db
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

but I get this error:

```
Creating network "backend_default" with the default driver
Creating backend_db_1 ... done
Creating backend_adminer_1 ... done
Attaching to backend_db_1, backend_adminer_1
adminer_1  | [Mon Apr  6 16:23:05 2020] PHP 7.4.4 Development Server (http://[::]:8080) started
db_1       | chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata: Operation not permitted
backend_db_1 exited with code 1
db_1       | chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata: Operation not permitted
backend_db_1 exited with code 1
db_1       | chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata: Operation not permitted
backend_db_1 exited with code 1
db_1       | chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata: Operation not permitted
backend_db_1 exited with code 1
db_1       | chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata: Operation not permitted
backend_db_1 exited with code 1
db_1       | chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata: Operation not permitted
backend_db_1 exited with code 1
```

I don't know why this happens!

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it is a bug on Windows. So yea no solution. Although following GitHub for the issue!